# In the behaviorism it is argued that we learn behavior, but (how) does this influence our way of thinking?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, behavior, behaviorism

I'm currently learning psychological approaches and social psychology, and this question popped into my head. The book on the approaches is: Glassman, W., Hadad, M. (20130116). Approaches to Psychology,  6th Edition.

If we look at a child, from the viewpoint of behaviorism, the child copies the behavior of the parents. Unlike the parents the child does not understand why certain behaviour is exhibited, because they don't understand the world. Could you say that someone's way of thinking is "shaped" by seeing and associating the behavior he / she sees as a child?

In other words, that a child is looking at the behavior of the parents and that he / she grows up to be a very analytical person or a very impulsive person. The thing that brought me to this was that as a child you resemble your mother in some areas and your father in others. That the mother takes an analytical approach to these specific situations, where the father might be impulsive.

I would like to hear your thoughts on this, did I go wrong somewhere?

Comment: I will be very interested in what answers come out if this question as the issues surrounding nature vs nurture is heavily debated. See [my post here](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/a/21594/7604) for more on what I mean